# "get a train from the station" or "get a train at the station"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do I have to use in the following sentence.

> You still can get a train to your destination **at**/**from** the station near the bank .

Comment: You can use either.

Comment: From means that it is departing from the station near the bank, while you can catch a train at the station near the bank.

Answer (score 2):

As Michael says, both can be used. Nevertheless, what I personally feel is that it depends on the context.

I'd use *from* the station in the context of *catching* a train or if the purpose is *journey*. On the other hand, if I'm just telling the *location* of a train, I may prefer *at*. Compare:

> Hurry, the train is *at* the station.

But,

> I am catching train *from* the station.

Thus, in your case, though *both* prepositions may work, I'd prefer *from.* We generally say *catch train **from** New York station, don't we?*

Comment: Yes. The trains to Manchester depart from London Euston, and arrive at Manchester Piccadilli.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence means the speaker suggests  the listener that he/she should catch the train at the nearby station.I think **at** / **from** the station seem to be the correct option  here.A train travel from one station to the other.But we can catch a train  from / at a particular  station.
Both the  prepositions are correct.

> **You still can get a train to your destination at/ from the station near the bank**

Here is the link

http://www.railmaps.com.au/journey_results.php?Origin=Sydney